# which package of tinyMCE is to be used?

Tags: php, tinymce, version

I want to use tinyMCE for adding content to front end. I got a link for downloading latest version of [tinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/download/download.php)

But I am confused to choose among TinyMCE 3.5.5 development package and TinyMCE 3.5.5.

Please let me know which one is suitable to implement. I am using php 5.2 with symfony 1.0 framework.

Thanks

Comment: what prevented you from asking this question on [TinyMCE support forum](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/)?

Comment: From Stackoverflow FAQ: [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Comment: @Jocelyn: I have asked this even on TinyMCE forum and they suggested to upgrade it. Now I need to know how to upgrade it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not really matter which one you choose, both with be exactly the same. The only difference is that TinyMCE Developer version will allow you to make changes to the source (which is javascript).

I have been using TinyMCE for a couple years now for custom Content Management Systems, and I have never felt the need or had a reason to edit the source.

**Conclusion:** The regular version 3.5.5 will almost certainly be good enough.

Answer (score 4):

Navigating to the official tinymce download page you will be offered 3 different versions of tinymce:

- TinyMCE 3.5.5 regular package
- TinyMCE 3.5.5 jQuery package
- TinyMCE 3.5.5 development package

The first one is the package for regular production use. This is usefull if you do not wish to make any changes to existing core files or add any custom plugins.

The second one is called "jQuery package". This one allows a developer to treat the tinymce editor instances as jQuery objects and use jQuery style like operations. (I strongly advise everyone not to use this package, because it is a source of trouble and is slow when it comes to keyboard input handling due to the object creation overhead).

The last one is a developer package. This one contains the regular build and can be used in the same way. By including `tiny_mce_dev.js` instead of the regular `tiny_mce.js` the non-minified tinymce files like classes and plugins are getting loaded and easier debugging is possible. It is a good choice to use this package if the downloader plans to write own plugins or develop/use a very complex tinymce configuration setting.

Comment: now I want to upgrade from current version to its newer version. Please let me know where all i need to change. should I need to replace old `tiny_mce.js` with new `tiny_mce.js`? Please help

Comment: you may totally overwrite all files of your old tinymce version with the newer files

Answer (score 1):

Use either one.

The Dev package just gives you bunch of extra stuff including a non-minified version of the script.